# Insert query failing in cassandra when using now()

Tags: cassandra

INSERT INTO testtable (id, user_name, gender, rank) VALUES (now(), 'test_user', 'MALE', 2) ;

Bad Request: line 1:60 no viable alternative at input 'now'

Can someone help on the above error message when trying to insert a timeuuid into a table in cassandra.

Comment: Which Cassandra version are you running?

Comment: @Richard, i am using cassandra 1.1.12

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade Cassandra - the timeuuid functions were added in Cassandra 1.2.2.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to insert a row using hector api where the primary key is(id,user_name)